# How to find one regex pattern is a subset of another?

Tags: javascript, regex

Two regex pattern are as follows

> pattern1 = "/api/v1/foo/bar/*"

and other say for example

> pattern2 = "/api/v1/*"

I want to ensure that the pattern which passes under `pattern1` passes under `pattern2` too.

For this, how to find that `pattern1` is the subset of `pattern2` programmatically? 
Any help in this regard is most welcomed.

Comment: `patt1.test(patt2)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan pattern2 is not a string it is another regex pattern. I want to ensure that anything that passes under pattern2 must pass in pattern1

Comment: @queenritchie - There is no way to do this. The only correlation is target strings between them. Generate an infinite random set of target strings and test them both out for unique matches. If _all_ don't match, the regex's diverge.

Comment: So you need to verify that patt2.test(s) => patt1.test(s) for each string s?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
var pattern1 = "/api/v1/foo/bar/*"
var pattern2 = "/api/v1/*"

var r2 = new RegExp ('^'+pattern2);
alert(r2.test(pattern1)) //true
```